# Define variable as list of contents of multiple files

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to declare a host variable in an Ansible YAML defaults file of a role, that should contain the content of multiple files as lists entries.

Consider the files `dir/1.txt` with the content `one` and `dir/2.txt` with the content `two`, so the variable should equal to `[ "one", "two" ]`.

To achieve that I am trying to combine the `fileglob` and `file` lookups, but I can't get it working.

---

My first idea was to just take the output of the `fileglob` lookup and take it as input for the `file` lookup like this, but that throws an error:

```yaml
myvar: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt')) }}"
```

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('file', lookup('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt')) }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /path/to/dir/1.txt,/path/to/dir/2.txt. could not locate file in lookup: /path/to/dir/1.txt,/path/to/dir/2.txt"}

---

The `fileglob` lookup does not seem to return an actual `list` of files, but a comma delimited string, as the output of this test playbook demonstrates:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: files
```

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "files": "/path/to/dir/1.txt,/path/to/dir/2.txt"
}
```

The [documentation of the `file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html) suggests that the module can take a list of files as input, but as separate terms. So if I only run the lookup on the two example files, it returns a comma delimited string of contents:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    contents: "{{ lookup('file', 'dir/1.txt', 'dir/2.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: contents
```

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "contents": "one,two"
}
```

---

Now I don't know how to convert the output of the `fileglob` lookup to multiple input terms for the `file` lookup. Also I am worried what happens if a file contains a `,` since I can't simply run `split(",")` on the output of the `file` lookup to receive a list, then.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying within the variables definition or do I have to resort to ansible logic and `set_facts` `with_fileglob`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is basically the difference between `lookup` and `query`, as explained in the documentation:

> The difference between `lookup` and `query` is largely that query will always return a list. The default behavior of `lookup` is to return a string of comma separated values. `lookup` can be explicitly configured to return a list using `wantlist=True`.

<sup>*Source: [Forcing lookups to return lists: `query` and `wantlist=True`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true)*</sup>

---

So, here, you want to use a `query` instead of a `lookup`:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: query('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt')
```

Giving:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  query('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt'):
  - /path/to/dir/1.txt
  - /path/to/dir/2.txt
```

---

As for passing the list of files from the `fileglob` lookup to the `file` one, you can unpack the list returned by `fileglob` with a star `*`, [like in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters).

So, your task ends up being

```yaml
- debug:
    var: "query('file', *query('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt'))"
```

Which would yield a list of the content of your files, as expected:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  query('file', *query('fileglob', 'dir/*.txt')):
  - one
  - two
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a ton! Didn't even know about query. :D